# Pandas - How to change values in the original excel workbook without changing the formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, xlrd

I wanted to know is there a way to open an excel workbook through **PANDAS** update some values in the original file keeping all data validations, formulas and formatting **as it was in the original file** and save it?

I can see similar question was posted here, but didn't got an answer and omits special fields:

[pandas to change the colum value withoutchanging the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573622/pandas-to-change-the-colum-value-withoutchanging-the-format)

I do understand this can be done through writer as described here:

[Changing formats of contents in columns in an existing Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479159/changing-formats-of-contents-in-columns-in-an-existing-excel-workbook)

but this would mean I need to redesign whole workbook in python with formatting, data validations countifs, etc which is just inhumane for the workbook I have to deal with.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas